# Using TCPDF to limit the amount of printing

Tags: php, tcpdf

Im using TCPDF to generate a PDF.  Im password protecting it:

```
$pdf->SetProtection(array('print', 'copy'), 'passwordhere', null, 0, null);
```

I would like to know if there is a way to allow printing but limit the amount of times it can be printed.  Example: 5 times

I know if I use something like Acrobat I can limit the amount of prints.  Is this possible with TCPDF?

Thanks.

Comment: 1 no, 2 its trivial to get around this silly limitation anyway

Comment: If I can print it once, I can print it a million times.  Print restrictions and even passwords are a relatively minor inconvenience to someone who really wants to use a document.  They're mostly wishful thinking to appease PHB requirements. Once a user has a document, you no longer have control.  Well, I guess on a Windows machine you might.

Comment: its a great way to annoy users, what happens when the printer runs out of ink?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I agree with all of you, however, it was a request from my client.  Thanks again!

Comment: you can, and should, say no to your client some times